# How to validate string using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate a string which donot have numeric characters.

If my string is "javaABC"   then it must be validated
If my string is "java1"  then it must not be validated

I want to restrict all the integers.

Comment: This kind of question can easily be answered by creating a small test program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
String  Text        = ...;
boolean HasNoNumber = Text.matches("^[^0-9]*$");
```

'`^[^0-9]*$`' = From Start(^) to end ($), there are ([...]) only non(^) number(0-9). You can use '\D' as other suggest too ... but this is easy to understand.

See more info [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/).

Comment: Perhaps it's easier for a regexp newbie to understand hasDigits = Text.matches("[0-9]") ?

Comment: "^\\D*$" is a shorter form ;)

Comment: @Brian: `Text.matches("[0-9]")` means "Text" consists of exactly one digit; you would need to say `Text.matches("(?s).*[0-9].*")` -- Java's funny that way.  OTOH, @NawaMan's regex doesn't really need the anchors: `Text.matches("[^0-9]*")` or `Text.matches("\\D*")` work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
\D
```

"\D" matches non-digit characters.

Answer (score 2):

More detail is here:
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way that you can search for a digit in a String:

```
public boolean isValid(String stringToValidate) {
   if(Pattern.compile("[0-9]").matcher(stringToValidate).find()) {
       // The string is not valid.
       return false;
   }

   // The string is valid.
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest to understand is probably matching for a single digit and if found fail, instead of creating a regexp that makes sure that all characters in the string are non-digits.